# How to access local env variables from ANT file

Tags: batch-file, ant

I have this ANT file that calls a batch file to set the environment variables, before these environment variables are referred to in the ANT script.

So my batch file (set_env.bat) contains:

```
REM ------ ECLIPSE ------
SET DIR_ECLIPSE=C:\Eclipse
SET DIR_ECLIPSE_MARS=%DIR_ECLIPSE%\eclipse-dsl-mars-2-win32
SET DIR_DEST=C:\mydsl\generated
```

Then my ANT script will call it like this:

```
 <target name="setvars" >
    <exec executable="cmd">
      <arg value="/c"/>
      <arg value="set_env.bat"/>
      <arg value="-p"/>
    </exec>
  </target>
 <property environment="env"/>
 <property name="tool" value="${env.DIR_ECLIPSE_MARS}" />
 <property name="destDir" value=${env.DIR_DEST}" />
 <target name="create_run_jar">
    <copy file="${env.DIR_ECLIPSE_MARS}/plugins/org.eclipse.xtext_2.9.1.v201512180746.jar"
          todir="${destDir}/myDsl_lib" />
 </target>
```

I keep on getting an error saying the file cannot be found and when I print the log via , I get "[echo] ${env.DIR_ECLIPSE_MARS}". So this means that the env vars are not set.

During copy, it displays this log:

```
D:\mydsl\antbuild.xml:129: Warning: Could not find file D:\mydsl\${env.DIR_ECLIPSE_4_5_2}\plugins\org.eclipse.xtext_2.9.1.v201512180746.jar to copy.
```

I execute the setvars target first followed by the create_run_jar.

Comment: Have you tried to `export` the env variables? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71144/what-do-the-bash-builtins-set-and-export-do

Comment: This approach will not work. The `cmd` instance is changing its own copy of the environment block, `ant` will not see any change. You can try the inverse approach: make the `cmd` instance define the variables and start the `ant` file. This way the `ant` task will inherit the variables of the `cmd` instance